# Dropdown таблица в Bootstrap меню

Tags: menu, bootstrap, css

Меню на Bootstrap, выпадающий список - все отображается в один столбец.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
*Столбец1*
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
*Столбец2*
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
```

Как сделать несколько столбцов?

Comment: http://bootstrap-ru.com/components.php - вот здесь очень подробно написано

Comment: а какие силы вас заставляют dropdown-menu делать обязательно списком ?

Comment: Поищите по запросу "bootstrap dropdown menu multi-column" или посмотрите статью на сайте [http://alijafarian.com/](http://alijafarian.com/bootstrap-multi-column-dropdown-menu/)

Comment: @rogueCapella: ссылки могут быть уместны в комментариях, но для ответа этого недостаточно. Подробнее тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. А предложение погуглить вовсе неуместно на SO, т.к. поисковики как правило приводят обратно (часто на тот же вопрос).

Answer (score 1):

уберите "class="dropdown-menu" role="menu""